# Nexus 7 Keeps Crashing When Sliding Edges?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've seen Ubuntu Touch successfully running on Nexus 7 wifi (2012), they are able to open an App then slide left/right to either hide the app or to make the launch bar visible. Regardless of what I do or what app i run Ubuntu freezes when i try to slide either way. Is there anyone that can say which version they have used with success for their Nexus 7 wifi (2012) ?

Currently just using this command to install:

```
phablet-flash ubuntu-system --channel stable --bootstrap
```

Which installs Ubuntu 13.10 (r101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using `--revision 83` which seems to be the original release back in October.